# configfs USB gadget write() call hangs

Tags: c, linux, usb, hid

I'm trying to emulate a HID device (a gamepad for PS3) from a Raspberry Pi Zero using configfs with kernel v4.19.40 (pretty much the same process as described [here](https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383)). Following the instructions in [gadget_hid.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt), I was able to get a working prototype that is able to send button presses from the Pi Zero to a USB host (a PS3). However, when some state changes on the USB host (i.e. a certain game is started), the program freezes. `strace` says that it is stuck on a call to `write()` to the configfs HID file (`/dev/hidgX`, in my case `/dev/hidg0`). How could the USB host block the device from sending data? If the USB host is not ready to receive, won't it just ignore the data sent?

In debugging I found [this patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/072684e8c58d17e853f8e8b9f6d9ce2e58d2b036) which seemed to be related but I saw no change after applying it.

Here is a small code sample (the full version can be found in [gadget_hid.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt)) that produces the same problem:

```c
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  int fd = 0;
  char report[8];
  int to_send = 8;
  fd_set rfds;

  if ((fd = open("/dev/hidg0", O_RDWR, 0666)) == -1) {
    perror("/dev/hidg0");
    return 3;
  }

  while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

    // Generate some data to send
    fill_report(&report);

    // Gets stuck here
    write(fd, report, to_send);
  }

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure -1 and not 0 is error for open?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine as it says in the docs, I can successfully write to `/dev/hidg0` and the HID data is successfully consumed by the USB host (the PS3), but only when starting a certain application on the host does `write()` call hang.

Comment: please make explicit in your problem description that you are compiling and running this on a RpiZero. Or are you just communicating to it? Good luck.

Comment: It's running on the RPi Zero, using configfs to act as USB device. Made some edits to that effect